# Commenting out regex, javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

Apologies if this has already been covered - perhaps i am searching for the wrong thing.

The following commented out line generates a syntax error:

`/* /[foo].*/ */`

It seems that the '*/' within the regex is confused with the end of the comment.

Is there a way to safely comment out blocks of code containing regular expressions?

Comment: Escape the `/`, `/* /[foo].*\/ */`, or since it is a single line comment, use `//`

Comment: What context is this used in? Show at least three lines from your code.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus why do you want three lines ? It's a made up example to illustrate the point. The context is literally any time you want to comment out some code for whatever reason and that code contains a regex line which ends with an asterisk.

Sounds like the correct answer is that there is no way to comment out a block of code without individually checking any lines of regex in it.

Comment: It does not matter if it is regex or not. You could have `var myString = 'opps! */';` or `// single-line comment to */ ruin your day!` and the same issue would present itself. Your specific regex example can be solved by escaping the forward slash so that it is regex and block-comment compatible but there is no universal solution.

Comment: It's an error because you can't include `*/` in the comment, otherwise it terminates the comment and then `*/` is left by itself to error out.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can't "escape" anything in comments. ;) All you did was add another character to break it up. Adding any character would be just as good.

Answer (score 0):

This subject rises in many programming languages.

I mark places that look like comment ends with special chars, so I can easily find them later to undo the comment. First it looks like this:

```
/* comment start here

   var emailBlabla = someString.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '');

comment ends here */
```

Then:

```
/* comment start here

   var emailBlabla = someString.replace(/^\sx*x/x, '').replace(/\s*$/, ''); // <<< note x*x/x

comment ends here */
```

Now whenever I want to uncomment, I just look for the sequence x*x/x.

Note that this doesn't work with tags, e.g. context Fluid/TYPO3:

```
<f:comment>
```

If you want to "deactivate" this tag without removing it, this won't work:

```
x<fx:xcomment>
```

Because the parser still sees a tag with namespace, and the namespace just changed to fx. In the context of tags, you have to break with space.

```
x < f x : xcomment>
```

But even then you have a clearly marked situation where you can work with find/replace.

Answer (score -1):

It's an error because you can't include `*/` in the comment, otherwise it terminates the comment and then the last `*/` is left by itself to error out. Just add a space:

```
/* /[foo].* / */
```

Or comment out the WHOLE line:

```
// /[foo].*/
```

If you are possessing a string with code in it and adding comment blocks programmatically, then simply replace all `*/` with `* /`:

```
var final = '/*' + code.replace(/\*\//g, '* /') + '*/';
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, however commenting out the line won't help because the // isn't recognized inside a comment block.

Comment: While that's true, has nothing to do with the OP.  They said "commented out *line*", not multiple lines.  If it were I would have a different answer. ;) It's exactly right for the original question.